# EditText inside AlertDialog can't be setText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have  `EditText` in an `AlertDialog`, it is used for editing data fetched from a cursor. before editing, I want to show old data in the `EditText`. The following method is called from a `ContextMenu` item:

```
private void edit(final long rowId){
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
   final View editView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_dialog,null);
   new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle("Edit: " + cursor.getString(1))
      .setView(editView)
      .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         EditText nameView = (EditText)editView.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
         //why the following statement can't work?
         nameView.setText(cursor.getString(1));
         editData(rowId, nameView.getText().toString());
      }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
   .show();
}
```

I think it should be set before the dialog is created, so I have tried to move that statement elsewhere, but failed.

Comment: post whole activity code to understand your needs better.

Comment: post the logcat error report.

Comment: There is no error, only

Comment: The text of EditText in xml is "Name", and that statement doesn't change it to the value fetched from cursor, it remains its value "Name" and no exception occured.

Comment: The problem is solved. I have moved the view inflation to onContextItemSelected, and setText there. Thank you for your attention.